# Rxjs Sharing an observable subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a function with the following code:

```
private foo() {
    let obs: Observable<any> = this._http.get<number>('/foo')

    obs.subscribe(x=> {
        console.log("foo : " + x)
    });

     this.blah(obs)
}

private blah(obs: Observable<any>) {
    obs.subscribe(x => {
       console.log("blah : " + x)
    })
}
```

this code is indeed printing both `foo` and `blah`, howerver it also does my http call to `/foo` twice

I would like it to happen only once. I tried replacing the `subscribe` by `do` in the blah function but it doesn't work.
What's the issue here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct behavior. You're creating two subscriptions and since the `http.get` creates a "cold" Observable it makes two HTTP calls.

The easiest way to avoid this is to share the source Observable with the `share()` operator.

```
let obs = this._http.get<number>('/foo').share();
```

You could also create a `ConnectableObservable` with the `publish()` operator and connect to the shared source manually.

```
let obs = this._http.get<number>('/foo').publish();

obs.subscribe(x=> {
    console.log("foo : " + x)
});

this.blah(obs);

obs.connect();
```